# Move or animate map and marker synchronously

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a list with a bunch of `LatLng`. I need to animate a marker from one position to the other until the list ends (finishing point).

I'm using an interpolator (something like [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/MapsV2/Animator/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/mapsv2/animator/MainActivity.java) implementation from @CommonsWare[enter link description here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)) to animate the marker from a position to the other. At the same time, I'm also creating a polyline with generated points.

With the above, I have a working solution. If setting the map to max zoom (`21f`) and even if the interpolator is producing results at a speed greater than `16ms`, adding the polyline and the marker at the new position does not impact the UI, that is, as far as my eyes can see, it's very smooth. Of course, at some point, the marker goes out of the screen and I have to move the map with my finger to track the marker and polyline movement.

I now want the marker stay always at the centre of the screen thus the map must move.

I've tried to use `map.moveCamera` and `map.animateCamera` but then the UI sometimes gets a little sluggish. I can see that the marker does not move as smooth as before. This is using `map.moveCamera` because with `map.animateCamera` I have even worst results.

In the function that the `ObjectAnimator` calls everytime it interpolates the point, I'm doing this:

```
public void onNewPosition(LatLng newPosition){
    marker.setPostion(newPosition);
    map.moveCamera(marker.getPosition())
}
```

If I wrap the above in an `if` condition to check if the time elapsed from the previous call to this one is greater than `16ms`, I still have some sluggish UI.

I've identified the problem in the map movement. Don't know if it's the matter that the UI cannot render the map movement and marker movement at the same time, thus, it seems that sometimes the marker moves and the map don't and other times is the other way around (don't know if I'm correct or not)

Any idea of how can I move the map and the marker at the same time or other solution that fulfils my needs, that is, move the marker and the map so that the user perception is that the marker is moving but staying at the centre of the screen while the map below performs the required movement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Could you perhaps imbed your map in two scrolling objects: a HorizontalScrollView and a VerticalScrollView, so you can approximate your movement by a vertical and a horizontal scroll? Use a viewport for the map view that encompasses the endpoints of your trip. Scroll the map view when the focal position changes instead of calling moveCamera. The idea is to shift the redrawing overhead to the graphics engine (which ought to be very good at it) instead of the map API. [I used a similar view architecture to scroll a train schedule, and it worked very well.]

Comment: Thanks, Walter but how I embed the map in two scrolling objects?

Comment: In your layout file, you have a map fragment. Surround it with an HSV, and surround that with a VSV. Or vice versa. Calculate an incremental scroll amount as an (x, y) pair using simple cartesian coordinates [you're probably already doing this because the scale of your map is probably such that a locally orthogonal coordinate system is accurate enough, but don't forget to scale the vertical motion based on latitude]. Use the scrollTo methods of your HSV and VSV objects to control the movement. The imbedded map should move the way you want.

Comment: Thanks. Will look into that but I can have multiple zoom levels so this can be difficult.